# Correct syntax of @if @else ladder in Laravel blade

Tags: laravel

I am trying to show the no. of notifications to user, using a badge, whose logic is as follows

- if the no. of notifications is greater than 0 but less than **7**,
  the badge colour is green (`badge-success`)
- if the no. of notifications is greater than 7 but less than **15**,
  the badge colour is yellow (`badge-warning`)
- if the no. of notifications is greater than **15**, the badge colour
  is red (`badge-danger`)

So far I tried using this in Laravel Blade, but it is not changing colour. It stays green (`badge-success`)

```
<span class="badge 
    @if(auth()->user()->notifications != 0)
        badge-success 
    @elseif(auth()->user()->notifications > 7) 
        badge-warning 
    @elseif(auth()->user()->notifications > 15)
        bg-danger 
    @endif" id="notfs">

    @if(auth()->user()->notifications != 0)
        {{ auth()->user()->notifications }} 
    @endif
</span>Notifications
```

I suppose there is some syntax error, but could be some logic error ?

Comment: I would assume that the User model has a relationship to Notification named `notifications`?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: then `auth()->user()->notifications` is returning a Collection (not a count) which is an object which is != 0

Comment: no, the `notifications` column in the `users` table has a number (0, 1,2 etc.) which is obtained depending on the no. of notifications in the `Notification` table against a `user_id` foreign key

Comment: then as long as they have any notifications then the first condition is met ... so the logic is wrong, it is upside down

Comment: @lagbox I tried that, but it's still not changing colour. It stays red in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the conditions upside down basically. At the moment if they have any notifications at all the first condition is true so it never will reach the `elseif` parts.

```
@if(auth()->user()->notifications > 15)
    danger
@elseif(auth()->user()->notifications > 7)
    warning
@elseif(auth()->user()->notifications != 0)
    success
@endif
```

Comment: So, I suppose ther eis nothing wrong with my syntax ?

Comment: sorry, there is nothing wrong with the syntax, just the logic was reversed